# How to remove erroneous values from a column in R

Tags: r

To preface I am new to R and programming in general,

I have 5 columns of data I am analyzing which each contain values which must be trimmed before analysis. The values which must be trimmed are all represented as "-8", and "-9".

`GROUPEDDATA1$V161081<-gsub("-8","-9","",as.character(GROUPEDDATA1$V161081))`

This code removes all values from the column and replaces them with "", not just "-8" and "-9". Is there a simpler way to go about removing these values from the columns?

Comment: Please share some data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: The posted code will not do as you say. The first arg to `gsub` is the regular expression pattern you want to match. You are saying match `-8`. The second argument is what you want to you want to replace `-8` with, you specify you want to replace it with `-9`. The third argument is the character vector for which you want to do the replacement, you specify a one element vector that is `""`. So nothing will get replaced. The fourth argument is a logical argument for if you want to ignore the case when pattern matching. You specify `as.character(GROUPEDDATA1$V161081)`, which won't do anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove", and for what sort of analysis? Replacing them with empty strings `""` doesn't seem ideal. Usually either replacing them with missing values `NA` or deleting the row they're in (filtering the data) is preferable.  For replacing them with `NA`, whatever command you're using to read in the data probably has an argument called something like `na.strings` where you could specify that `-8` and `-9` are to be read in as `NA`, and then you don't have to deal with them later.

Comment: And, since you're coercing the column to `character` class in this command, it makes me worried that the other values in the column are numbers and should probably be kept as numbers not forced to be `character`. Sample data, as Quinten suggests, would be very very helpful to see. `dput(GROUPEDDATA1[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows, or maybe `dput(GROUPEDDATA1[1:10, "V161081", drop = FALSE])` for the first 10 rows of just that column---choose a suitable subset that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `apply` to apply a certain function over multiple columns. In your `gsub` the pattern you are looking for is `-8|-9`, which means search for `-8` or `-9` and replace that with `""`. You can use the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("-8", "-9", "10"),
                 v2 = c("2", "4", "-9"))

apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("-8|-9", "", x))
```

Output:

```
     v1   v2 
[1,] ""   "2"
[2,] ""   "4"
[3,] "10" ""
```

Comment: Given the `as.character` in the question, *probably* the data starts out as numeric and converting it all to character is bad. Also `lapply` is probably better than `apply` here, if there are other columns that don't need trimming converting to matrix isn't a good idea. And it would probably be nice to show how to operate on a few specific columns within a larger data frame. And and empty strings probably aren't what's actually needed for whatever analysis OP wants to do... I'd recommend not answering until we get more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace` in `lapply`. *Example:*

```
dat
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  5  9
# 2 -8  6 10
# 3  3  7 -9
# 4  4  8 12

dat[] <- lapply(dat, \(x) replace(x, x %in% c(-8, -9), 9999))
dat
#     X1 X2   X3
# 1    1  5    9
# 2 9999  6   10
# 3    3  7 9999
# 4    4  8   12
```

Use anything you like instead of `9999`.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, -8, 3, 4), X2 = 5:8, X3 = c(9, 10, -9, 
12)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mutate(across()) to isolate the columns you want to change, and for each column use gsub. I've use positive look ahead to just remove the "-" prior to the 8 or 9, and I've required that this "-" is at the beginning.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), ~gsub("^-(?=[89])","", .x, perl=TRUE)))
```

Output:

```
    x1   x2   x3
1   45  815  8-9
2    8   85  898
3  hat  123  129
4 9876 9876    9
5  A-9    9 <NA>
```

Input:

```
df = data.frame(x1 =c("45", "-8", "hat", "-9876", "A-9"),
                x2 =c("815", "-85", "123", "9876", "-9"),
                x3 =c("8-9", "-898", "129", "-9", NA)
                )

     x1   x2   x3
1    45  815  8-9
2    -8  -85 -898
3   hat  123  129
4 -9876 9876   -9
5   A-9   -9 <NA>
```